# Data Binding between parent and child component in vue3 composition api

Tags: data-binding, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have successfully bound data in a two way format in vue 3 like this :

```
<template>
 <p for="">Year of Incorporation</p>
 <input type="text" v-model="input" />

    <div>
     {{ input }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    let input = ref("")
    return {input};
  },
};
</script>
```

What I want to do now is put the input inside a child component like this:

**Parent Component:**

```
<template>
 <Child v-model="input" />
{{input}}
</template>
```

**Child Component:**

```
<template>
 <input type="text" v-model="babyInput" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    let babyInput = ref("")
    return {babyInput};
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Vue.js documentation`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model) presents a nice way of handling `v-model`-directives with custom components:

- Bind the value to the child component
- Emit an event when the Child's input changes

You can see this example from the docs with the composition when you toggle the switch in the right-top corner (at https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model).

Comment: This doesn't help with the specific question, which uses the `setup()` approach.